# adding a book with multiple parameters to a single array list index

Tags: java

So I'm trying to add a book to an array list. I'm having a little trouble due to the fact the book must include 3 parameters (string author, string title, string id) The reason I'm having trouble is due to 2 methods that have to be used on it. One method is for finding matching titles the other wants me to list all books currently in the array. Right now my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
/**
* A class contaning books.
*
* @author ()
* @version (21/11/2021)
*/

public class Library
{
private ArrayList<String> books;
private String name;
/**
* Makes an arraylist and sets the librarys name
*/
public Library(String aName)
{
   books = new ArrayList<>();
   name = aName;
 }
/**
* Adds a book to the arraylist books
*/
public void addBook(String author, String title, String id)
 {
 books.add(author);
 books.add(title);
 books.add(id);
 }
 
/**
* calculates fine of a late book
*/public double calculateFine (double bookPrice, int dayLate)
{
   return (double) (bookPrice/50)*dayLate;
 }
/**
* creates a private list to store matched books
*/
public ArrayList<String> booksClone = new ArrayList<>();
/**
* 
*/
public ArrayList getMatchingBooks(String bookMatch) 
{
   for (int i =0; i < books.size(); i++)
   {
    if(books.get(i).equals(bookMatch));
    booksClone.add(bookMatch);
   }
    return booksClone;
 }
/**
  * 
  */
public boolean isAvailable(String book, boolean onLoan)
 {
  for (int i=0; i <books.size();i++)
  {
      if(books.get(i)==book)
      if (onLoan ==true);
     }
     return false;
 }
/**
  * Prints out all books currently listed.
  */
public void listAllBooks()
{for (int i=0; i < books.size();i++)
   System.out.println(books.get(i));
}
/**
* 
*/
public void loanBook(String bookLoan, boolean onLoan)
{
for (int i=0; i <  books.size();i++)
{
    if (books.get(i)==bookLoan)
    onLoan = true;
 }
}
/**
* 
*/
public void removeBook(String book)
{
 for (int i=0; i <  books.size();i++)
{
    if (books.get(i).equals(book))
    books.remove(book);
    else
    System.out.println("Book not found");
}
} 
}
```

as you can see my current code takes the title author and id and links them to separate index's so when i try to search for a title i can not find the author.
I'm sorry if this is a obvious question I think I've just gotten myself lost any help and or advice is appreciated.

Comment: The real answer here: abstractions. The same way you created a Library class to model a library ... you should model a Book class. Meaning: the library should keep a list of Book objects. Not a list that actually stores "tuples"  with title, author, id. Or a list (with all the books), and a HashMap that uses a book ID as key, and the "on loan" information as value.

Comment: Meaning: your model is that that the books list is filled with **tuples** (author, title, id). So, when you added 3 books, only slots 1, 4, and 7 have book **titles**. Sure, that can work, but then you have to ALWAYS remember that indexes 0, 0+3, 0+6 ... are authors, and 1, 1+3, 1+6 are titles, and so on. So, as said: the real solution for you is to create a class that represents a single book, and that you then can ask for title, author, ... and so on

Comment: Hey Ghostcat thank you for taking the time to try and help. I originally thought of that however this being for a course it uses a test bed to be marked. when I tried to create a new book class the test bed freaked out on me. I then tried to write them all together in book.add(author + title + id) and a few variations and while that left them all on the same index they weren't separated in a way that could be searched for individually.

Comment: Then the real answer for you is: talk to your peers, tutors, instructors. When you have trouble with such things, talk to them. And note, there is one way to make things work without a book class: you can use one array PER property. So you have an array for titles, one for authors, ... and a "book" is nothing but: a certain index. That will work for the initial tasks you have, but as soon as your code will need to deal with "lists of books", and different ordering for different lists, things will again get very complicted.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't allow you to define a class is sketchy as that appears to the natural approach to your task.  You could use parallel Lists or model a nook as a Map but that is a workaround. I suspect that your problem may simply be figuring out how to use the test bed.  I will second @Ghostcat's suggestion to talk to your instructor, TA, tutor, and/or fellow students.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the 3 String like this on the library arraylist, nothing will link them together.
To save the 3 String togeter on the list, you need to create an Object - lets name it "Book" - that will have 3 variables: author, title & id.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
/**
* A class contaning books.
*
* @author ()
* @version (21/11/2021)
*/

public class Library {
  private ArrayList<Book> books;
  private String name;
  /**
  * Makes an arraylist and sets the librarys name
  */
  public Library(String aName) {
     books = new ArrayList<>();
     name = aName;
   }
  /**
  * Adds a book to the arraylist books
  */
  public void addBook(String author, String title, String id) {
   books.add(new Book(author, title, id));
   }

  /**
  * calculates fine of a late book
  */public double calculateFine (double bookPrice, int dayLate) {
     return (double) (bookPrice/50)*dayLate;
   }
  /**
  * creates a private list to store matched books
  */
  public ArrayList<String> booksClone = new ArrayList<>();
  /**
  *
  */
  public ArrayList getMatchingBooks(String bookMatch) {
     for (int i =0; i < books.size(); i++)
     {
      if(books.get(i).equals(bookMatch));
      booksClone.add(bookMatch);
     }
      return booksClone;
   }
  /**
    *
    */
  public boolean isAvailable(String bookTitle, boolean onLoan) {
    for (int i=0; i <books.size();i++)
    {
        if(books.get(i).title==bookTitle)
        if (onLoan ==true);
       }
       return false;
   }
  /**
    * Prints out all books currently listed.
    */
  public void listAllBooks() {for (int i=0; i < books.size();i++)
     System.out.println(books.get(i));
  }
  /**
  *
  */
  // public void loanBook(String bookLoan, boolean onLoan) {
  // for (int i=0; i <  books.size();i++) {
  //     if (books.get(i)==bookLoan)
  //     onLoan = true;
  //  }
  // }
  /**
  *
  */
  public void removeBook(String bookId) {
   for (int i=0; i <  books.size();i++) {
      if (books.get(i).id.equals(bookId))
      books.remove(i);
      else
      System.out.println("Book not found");
  }
  }
  class Book {
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String id;
    public Book (String author, String title, String id) {
      this.author=author;
      this.title=title;
      this.id=id;
    }
    public String toString(){
      return id+": "+title+" from "+author;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Library lib = new Library("lib1");
    lib.addBook("Mr X", "title1", "0");
    lib.addBook("Mr X", "an other title", "8");
    lib.addBook("Ms Y", "last title", "213b");
    lib.listAllBooks();
  }
}
```

Ps: Please add tab on your code.